# How can I copy physics (not rigid body) to multiple objects

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

I have 774 fractured pieces and I want them all to interact with a fluid simulation (flip fluid), however I can’t find a way to make them all physics objects at once, and I don’t want to go through one by one. CTRL + L > Modifiers doesn’t work, and holding alt while performing the action doesn’t work either.

Comment: Could you accept the answer, so the thread gets marked as solved?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select them all.
2. Add and configure the fluid settings on the active one
3. Press CRTL + L -> Copy Modifiers

Comment: Copy modifiers doesn’t seem to work, since this is physics, not modifiers.

Comment: the fluid settings create a modifier. In my tests, it worked.

Comment: Are you using mantaflow or flip fluids? Another thing is that the objects are just collisions foe the fluid, which might not create a modifier